# Sub-Query Gives Me Different Result

Tags: mysql

I have this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM gross_profit
WHERE client_name = 'john'
AND timestamp = 'lm153-1531439443738'
```

and here's the result :

```
+--------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| id     | client_name | timestamp           | profit_loss | profit_loss_unit | profit_loss_type |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| 500392 | john        | lm153-1531439443738 |  1.90000000 | ADA              | profit           |
| 500393 | john        | lm153-1531439443738 |  0.00210900 | USDT             | fraction         |
| 500394 | john        | lm153-1531439443738 |  0.00000000 | BTC              | normal           |
| 509189 | john        | lm153-1531439443738 | -1.43713843 | ADA              | fee              |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

now, I want to eliminate any `timestamp` which has `profit_loss_type = fee`.

so I modify my query into this :

```
SELECT *
FROM gross_profit
WHERE client_name = 'john'
AND timestamp = 'lm153-1531439443738'
GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss_type = 'fee' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

and of course the result : `Empty set (0.01 sec)`

but why, when I use that query as sub-query :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT timestamp
    FROM gross_profit
    WHERE client_name = 'john'
    AND profit_loss > 0
    GROUP BY timestamp
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN profit_loss_type = 'fee' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) AS t1
WHERE t1.timestamp = 'lm153-1531439443738'
```

it gives me : `1 row in set (0.60 sec)` and `lm153-1531439443738` shows as result.

this really confuse me. why the result is different when I use as a single query and as sub-query?

Comment: I guess because one query considers profit_loss, while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of the WHERE condition :

```
AND profit_loss > 0
```

which is executed **before** the HAVING condition.

Then, the "fee" profit_loss type is filtered_out before, and your result is not empty any more.

Try to remove this line.

Comment: you're right, bro! thank you so much for your answer

Comment: I will. but stackoverflow says must wait 6 minutes.